# Href link target Open in same tab in Mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento

In Magento 1.9.0.1 using Owl carousel for display new arrival products. If I click the first product in desktop view it should open in new tab but in mobile view, same should open in the same tab.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Which magento version and frontend (e.g. RWD or Luma) are you using? Could you add the source code of the link or `window.open()` to your question pls?

Comment: Magento 1.9.0.1 and rwd.. Can you please share the clear code here following <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"> this link in desktop view should open in new tab and same link in mobile in same tab

Comment: Any one help with this

Answer (score 2):

If you set the target attribute to "_blank", the link will open in a new browser window or a new tab.

Comment: But in mobile view i need in same tab.. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to detect a mobile device in JavaScript and change target attribute.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    document.getElementById("link").target = "_self";     //change target
}
```

HTML code -like this:

```
<a id="link" href="/something" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: I used this code in owl carosuel in magento if i click first product image in mobile view it is opening in same tab. If click 2nd product image in same carosuel it is opening in new tab. the following code 


<a target="_blank"<a id="link" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(270); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" />
</a>

Comment: <script>
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    document.getElementById("link").target = "_self";     //change target
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: This is not working can you please share the full code